# Implement CKEditor with AngularJS (pasteState event)

Tags: angularjs, ckeditor

I use CKEditor in my AngularJS webapp. I defined the event `pasteState` to listen to text changes and copy it to my `ng-model`.

Today, I upgraded CKEditor from version `4.4.7` to `4.5.1` (the last one) and discovered that my `pasteState` event is never fired.

**My directive with the `change` event:**

```
appDrct.directive('ckEditor', function() {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function($scope, $elm, attr, ngModel) {

            var config = {
                toolbar:[[ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'TextColor', 'FontSize', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyRight' ]]
            };
            config.removeButtons = '';
            config.fontSize_sizes = 'petit/12px;normal/14px;grand/16px;';

            var ck = CKEDITOR.inline ($elm[0], config);

            if (!ngModel) return;

            //ck.on('pasteState', function() {
            ck.on('change', function() {
                console.log(ck.mode);
                $scope.$apply(function() {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData() || '');
                });
            });    

            ngModel.$render = function (value) {
                ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
            };

            $scope.$on("$destroy",function() {
                CKEDITOR.instances[ck.name].destroy();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should listen to the following events:
`dataReady`, `change`, `blur`, `saveSnapshot`.

From source code of [ng-ckeditor](https://github.com/lemonde/angular-ckeditor/blob/master/angular-ckeditor.js#L43):

```
['dataReady', 'change', 'blur', 'saveSnapshot'].forEach(function(event) {
  ckeditor.$on(event, function syncView() {
    ngModel.$setViewValue(ckeditor.instance.getData() || '');
  });
});
```

But, my suggestion is to reuse a project that already exists, if you find something wrong or that can be improved you may suggest a modification (pull request) and make reusable code.

In a brief search I found two good projects:

- https://github.com/lemonde/angular-ckeditor
- https://github.com/esvit/ng-ckeditor

**EDIT:**

If you really want a simple version, you can use this [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cPTr7/670/):

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('ckEditor', [function () {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {
            var ck = CKEDITOR.replace(elm[0]);

            ck.on('change', function() {
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
                });
            });

            ngModel.$render = function (value) {
                ck.setData(ngModel.$modelValue);
            };

            $scope.$on("$destroy",function() {
                ck.destroy();
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to be dependent on someone's code; I want to understand everything and these solutions seems way too heavy for me... See my updated question, I've added my directive but the `change` event is never fired

Comment: I was using a custom version of ckeditor without the Undo plugin (which is the plugin which fires the `change` event!)

Answer (score 1):

There's no "pasteState" in the public API of CKEditor, so it seems weird trying to use something like that (what kind of relation can exists between content changes and state of Paste?)

It seems that you should use '[change](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-change)' instead.

Comment: I'm in wysiwig mode and for some reason the change event is not fired! I've added the piece of code (directive) I'm using...

Comment: I don't know what's a "directive". Try with plain javascript and you'll see that the change event works.